# Related rate of a falling ladder

Tags: calculus

The question is as follows: A 10-foot ladder is sliding down a wall. The top of the ladder is moving at a constant rate of 3 feet per second. What is the rate of change in the angle that the ladder makes with the ground when the base of the ladder is 6 feet from the wall?

I get `-5/18 rad/s` as my answer but that does not seem to be correct.

I have `x/10 = cos(θ)`, the first derivative being `d(θ)/dt = dx/dt*(1/-10sin(θ))`. Sin(θ) = 8/10 making the full thing `dθ/dt= 3(-1/(10(8/10)))` which gives me -5/18 rad/s.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the distance from the top of the ladder to the  ground. Then $\sin \theta=y/10$ or $\theta= \arcsin(y/10)$. Differentiating by $t$ we get $\large{\frac{d \theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{100-y^2}}\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{3}{\sqrt{100-y^2}}=-\frac{1}{2}}$ (when $y=8$)

Comment: When the base of the ladder is $6~\text{ft}$ from the wall, $y = 8~\text{ft}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thank you for spotting my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind that from

$$
x^2+y^2=l^2\\
x = l\cos\theta\\
y = l\sin\theta
$$

we have

$$
\dot x x + \dot y y = 0\\
\dot x =-l\sin\theta\dot \theta
$$

so

$$
\dot x x_0 + \dot y_0 y = 0\Rightarrow \dot x = -\frac{\dot y_0}{x_0}y
$$

here $x_0 = 6,\dot y_0 = -3, l = 10$ so 
$$
l\sin\theta\dot\theta = \frac{\dot y_0}{x_0}y = \frac{\dot y_0}{x_0}l\sin\theta
$$

and finally

$$
\dot\theta = \frac{\dot y_0}{x_0} = -\frac{3}{6}=-\frac 12
$$

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes seems to be you are given the top of the ladder is moving at a constant of $3$ feet per second.

We are not given that $\frac{dx}{dt}=3.$

Note that we have:

$$x^2+y^2=10^2$$

$$2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

Comment: So dy/dt = 3 then? Given the equation you have how would I use that to get an angle?

Comment: You just have to find the value of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ wrong right. Find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ from $\frac{dy}{dt}, x, y$ and then substitute it back to your original working.